# data frame sorting using column and row characters to match taxa annotations to different samples

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to sort my taxonomic annotations (16S dataset) based off of columns 'sample', 'Family', and 'taxa'.  Briefly, there are two sample types; m3ofair and m3NC, and I wish to know the unique ASV identifier in column 'taxa' if the annotation in 'Family' are identical across both sample types.

For example, the annotation 'f__Beijerinckiaceae' in column 'Family' is present in both samples, m3ofair and m3NC.  Since this is the case, I would like to know the ASV taxa identifier for all three annotations of 'f__Beijerinckiaceae', which are 2ca928ad9749bb9726c35d6528fefec1, bcc8b318ede81a8b211e7bdd1531baec, and e31f3d32519dc9021ff790f87d76114c.

Thank you in advance!

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(taxa = structure(c(203L, 150L, 150L, 202L, 175L
), .Label = c("8c54f0af4445cdb1a6a36304a80b5a6d", "e6ff53b2675c61cf25ad3d79917b318e", 
"38bbf752453c1c64f2e61966016d45c5", "903bcbbcb2ac130bb32d847ca7d191ed", 
"7fc0ccbd86b09190f44369a934b3456c", "03c095b4239af5a7f63d39522b34186b", 
"513c1bcb314fbf047f366f84a646c4a2", "0d3dca27868f7cfabbdbe1eb90657340", 
"4b36fd18a35f063166412a83379bf797", "a6a6601f3a675697e92bc24d32042929", 
"c46477febff8e68314f5baa81f4c082f", "f8753b9f13abb306b57aedce2cf6e7d0", 
"230363069727610f8f1546cb314f2d1a", "100f4d61f5eaf8fb7369d9583b32ba46", 
"69a70c343722f6851fc2191d4b3c3a1b", "0f222d9f6f748209e5d39cbbbb704c3e", 
"06b8e39b562a2b31643b4f2c00d5dec7", "51141f001e298a5e44d99f7d7bdb78e2", 
"56c98126dde3abb2d263088db55e12c8", "d8adf2a20249cefe6c627f9c17abb202", 
"4e3acf7a1c4dddbc3f68097207cacb66", "fadd6b74d7cc847716a19679be001724", 
"9815d07f1b564c9be5aab03db01608da", "bdd1f036611254ef872b334f7da681e6", 
"028ecb2ed02be346c5f0347a9a3fba2a", "0310f41e594c49368dde5c5993a7a5d0", 
"f510252f2eef402050f8169436cb4501", "3cb9f6500275fabe7c87a599a8c31749", 
"f148144695ed0a63b976ea05243aba8c", "9ed070c666e12720a6bb6d3df1b09e45", 
"e54bcf1c8ec24811e7c355b8d82fa59e", "c6608772f41c7d2202f2504190f2af8a", 
"78732fda4b5a16d2bdddcd553953752c", "46271ec11fc9f127649526834a9fd805", 
"dd0eaf58cb0b5378f465b4f59adf79d2", "585ab9ce79a8c90d675a66b9678b2137", 
"4ef5dabd754e48c26c66c55b3615e69f", "bc3043f80a5fe9e5faa189fa7b050f61", 
"f570f293e6b304776e5dce910a0b96e8", "432f8ae2390df378d7bab37a0026ff03", 
"0d959da770b454f90e53757f8ab0893f", "0bc8e7f6bf04c1e745749edeb6d6628d", 
"c78a82f200050febc553de67fffef578", "da36821195d462457b39c41aeb611ba1", 
"2de266b1ffa8e9ec6383c98096caf8f0", "3845a467d4d557e0f035d045d0d86f70", 
"630afd8b62db24d65410329610383a4f", "bfbf3b84b315e741c4345ebb43e2b9cc", 
"c85df4c87e8960b573d8ae4bf7f65e15", "6c46511a89ec2a070fef341371ad02b7", 
"6307431a0a1a9d90045dc5dccbfc5fe9", "0d1bf49752cd0c9211d28bc8577a9145", 
"11630fb56d652f032964d7567e083d40", "04caec30dc35c55d62d69e6125cec2c1", 
"854aeab59d32bfddbea09ed0571ca007", "f6436e7085d15342388e67b55d692fb6", 
"ecbf086d6ccbe5e8c2a69d0afb144662", "da247df6fe91b74bf38d3ecc1c05b4b0", 
"d4c4725af861d3daa18bddefb558cf50", "c06b07ff323a7b0bccf5d0e604b0afab", 
"ec8bf881537838f56323ada7de070b19", "1d6f8731081df8944cd50ae875fb9b28", 
"8101da5193e402ec2741419cd0515110", "381f3c0f833ce81483700d6dc0b940ef", 
"d0484307102691e2482cb79f8784827c", "d0c9e10ee52d3c93502663df3328e2c6", 
"2f09559bc1ffcc3ea06ae2766194920b", "3bb215c036a5b86e071708ce88665689", 
"d8a6777829870b41d1544fb173608685", "10a4a0714d1b0063c37636f2ec22bbae", 
"5740f0ff513cc2099d6beacec9336f45", "763f0806ad9068d1f4092259a970c925", 
"50e96bbd1a8267119529843a1acb43a5", "500d6b485cef4c52aad211d6d6e6dbc7", 
"4ea5683e2c2a183c11c45dc8fbd0c67c", "7e598ad34909a3fb8ff1623f1ede11a6", 
"8659c05e82a2d1399cbc3fd26ab938e4", "9c886b1c9e3e2ec63e0dbbd085996334", 
"8da02c7114ba0d9ee40312926e037a8f", "5cb28bd0b2eea6847a6328712217c141", 
"a049763053c277b16c2a318f41eb23b4", "0ce84d495f51f4e5997076bddebe65a5", 
"576fd9e4a384474af1d78a589118b213", "e74212c56f84c309729e86ad3b126716", 
"095249b545f554a6a66a4e378eed9c23", "12f69cdd5a43e9c04fa76fe778493dbc", 
"6eaaffd8bd37b95220a3bebdf503be32", "78d6bb358b0ec0c94a8caa7c7a28171c", 
"57799c0748039c006705cb9c46ace954", "b335608a8c2309ce02373311b7737b55", 
"ff4bc2548279113788b4bf164d2db0d0", "254ba9ed4527552e061da0653ae95392", 
"2480590c44af81ddbc2f34d381864702", "e4b865c957d0d23766a0e8e87f6d153d", 
"f98cc8f203873fd4078c589a6332e72e", "4eb88a4d445e0987c56d0197301bd4e7", 
"c5f7ff7e9d319f880b2c41c4ce6d52de", "15e687c6e5701e1b3b10fc0223d96c59", 
"5c3138b23334b1d6b4bf3943db5eae74", "e22be263cc3a006762b66711df3d6a23", 
"e209a5a9add3e7a68f273a2f17942555", "b19efe6ae9dabd64b44e12f4f1b88643", 
"ea0c2938cf670cfcec8bd497e1767ae8", "ea794ad075da6b9b427ecf13244a6e97", 
"414cb56f046e21beb8cf72b9285ab2bd", "6f318147a66f5851564f04aba9092057", 
"32b53bb775ee918b4b75ee4c87ecdb55", "f467d11f3c1a16ea55e2ab7ab88a85c2", 
"dfb69af34af0dcc91f9596d47ea6882b", "db4c51d23607a40db2843c49a38ee271", 
"02047d2e2da6d0e73846b63774619e77", "cb2fe0146e2fbcb101050edb996a0ee2", 
"4b88b52dd068a7d432309dec77813d29", "d2da0518d0f3ac5dd8d7df770389fee5", 
"5f86daf7f135fee1745dba9e874fe013", "9a2740e3bc27419a895dfb6e0b986854", 
"3a2e70f61b311dc0cd2261732a9cb627", "313402c6104b2605890eda8d9fa89fba", 
"e33cca4021036f12a70132aed9f9c52d", "d29fe3c70564fc0f69f2c03e0d1e5561", 
"eb5f185c6ab0e5f7953654a2a5d12ce7", "89fa7b79c6b2c5019ca0d1bc2f509f0b", 
"fcd4f95c05b868060121ff709085bf21", "7c14b01c89686b9e327fc7d3dee3af30", 
"0161e22acf37955da1e4b8bafe9f54e6", "ac70e87927f15bf812e8cad1cd9003cb", 
"bfbed36e63b69fec4627424163d20118", "3f0ecac3d878543cf67dae94e6309453", 
"0b607a251255e7aa0ef0c4e242b3e87c", "3d28edbfcb341fbf3d2fd87056633569", 
"fa2102f32f8f05f458f0833df8c78500", "3b588d7e9f41b7e5ea9539d52ccda834", 
"646eeb6a205282fe7afb5d73d1af30be", "a3e8652354170f4ddc4b96f65ff42aaf", 
"09b2620539f4861b9b2e6d271d4bb319", "a301810850607af459b6de0b8a6dfcfb", 
"ee2babc92e666c2593d83df7ad086362", "1054403160f296f2f44fbdf81f31b32c", 
"b62d8ace7310a137d1ff25156b20b881", "4043cc4801dcf236434002ac21298d76", 
"feb46b2df4fc3958ccd80e768b79502b", "c2dfc10913176eda134cd88ed68e0a72", 
"668584d4ca79707c62229c2b9a520634", "b48eec9298fe8ed0fdf2e968ee6cc4af", 
"a75e4ea5f1add4aa39f660dd13084fd0", "2a8bd6428138528c12a10c06b52954db", 
"e6922be77906565e6bae2a89da15d175", "e21e4030f895965d1846404a94ebcb11", 
"d03ede724dcc3efd39db449fd5bced6e", "6639f71cd3265109c47115f4a5913958", 
"8c08537b3e07c84c47eb29e4de593a02", "8c1456c47986f85320cdfe1c515ffb4c", 
"3e00fb174071bfc76c017d666f43af65", "1f70bd0eeef30f2afcd750b70f7e7066", 
"c1efd1322ab8cef2a84ace9e85e37467", "b18b389447d758e7cb173b4b4f2ad960", 
"9af604229897c70de75a7740fe13e80d", "c9a7a8206f0d8eda7576e0bb44b058a7", 
"ae65f0c53471069e8a19b8d38ffcd3e7", "b19b302de47cc21f8f4cf1464a10b2b3", 
"8b9a8bca0a4a02cde893f0bf550e4b68", "2492e30becb2716ccd9557e27900a56d", 
"997d9c1623cbaab34cdb0668950d5a08", "1c77f5f31494131fcbb21fd9f52c7618", 
"bfbd7ffe99a84ab5d92dc545d1a5a3c7", "e91fee71ae5261d22530ee9afa22dae5", 
"59988344137e8b4b1c56e5f886bc294d", "3a4d3ac6f2aeecdba4936b18e28d04e5", 
"e48dc10d2f3df1f6795902f9d53625ee", "9259758b55aa71398e2cafd0db077fcd", 
"61f0d618a9ccef240bf7f6b65ac3cd64", "955d8fcbb35e8bc04c8df0c6aae34d34", 
"35a7084609b22c35a5162738624ef6d0", "bc2942a64ee2fa191613f41f7e0134df", 
"e31f3d32519dc9021ff790f87d76114c", "594a57ff90b7936ce2cd8036ad681cef", 
"a64788b07ff4d444a278dbdd45b9cda4", "ef1e892b6e84a8b51d80eb7d6037167f", 
"ce036ee8825f6a2f95a01b9488144638", "5a4979556bf389cd5ba711b146417234", 
"ac809fd715cced98911f73f1dfb1ffb9", "e206fe2391a57543027d38d4ab4355e5", 
"780d57e7f37aba0e43ea58166978f258", "9995306be33bb6a067fbd14fd12ab247", 
"d867858df4524fe62a46ed814274aaa4", "12c0941446564e8d3cb6c3fb07bebed8", 
"d174fd25211450a7f7b6dbae6db61e2c", "491e6acf93836613376f546052749de2", 
"be94715fa59eebb39dae561eee3e2f3a", "21bc9a5af6203656e6d1066a13121fb0", 
"0b925631436d3775231b60f9d0011cae", "47c2b089e44e1baab72de03674f2526e", 
"c4d8bbf6d24dd9c56321087cc3936763", "147f2c2c24c7e1b1c371d42a36816214", 
"7c999fc012772119e945f6e87a941e92", "3423114aff9da85e4989c2c268769033", 
"82eab43c427e6afb5bf1fd10be00cc4b", "f637087afddcd520f0691150409f4d26", 
"54edafdb5df25d839fa4696a3d8a08d9", "bfa4fe32a85423441482e307c7ed5e65", 
"34d0e4410278fca5bbc2eac3de76feac", "bcc8b318ede81a8b211e7bdd1531baec", 
"2ca928ad9749bb9726c35d6528fefec1", "959a178855242ad3833af85d38ccff45", 
"3830e37a7ac6cf83a20dc9b8f225bb69", "9205f49b7a5898bf9dec93aa53ff96ec", 
"bf2b830db0f89f72b4bf68394b70fbf5", "cba5161b7eb1f07a14ca874577e69cf3", 
"179e215ab39a0a69ca15100615efae28", "beb5157c4f4ffcb17a5aa73fb6efd009", 
"38401e17915bca5aab62c763930d1cfb", "1fc7138b0d9568c4588eb34dabc430d3", 
"d2c5f354da4c7a6e78626761b1801770", "68089dfb5a592ef9b73c307c746a940e", 
"f8e8cca8fe936d9be35ed4fcf790d35b", "e68f3ead96583e125709c8a5ecf20a63", 
"06b48070c8d8e4ad997399e958871cea", "aff65597908099c9ee322aff6bec0a68", 
"c802baf89ae3088ec5027d645223e3d1", "59afa99ca520b0db55db192cf8be4edb", 
"e131d6b9e4f997788460a450a69c3a99", "1b448e00c078f81e49a61933072345d2", 
"0f48376fe94d49cef9a1ee1b46af7a4a", "79e9e337b10e2d298bb1b3bde946782d", 
"1868b3eae7d694c939f6ee777c98ee82", "909755d7142ea53c7f61c97c3586f26c", 
"c1bee78e8c05c7d1abd7122bff925e54", "3cdd97ba69a504117de24626ba790e96", 
"bfd74cfd3e6c2b27cffc14334ee55878", "e2603d057e6cc94b2b3c774e5b24c09c", 
"a7b2fd6bf0b1c028de90c11becdc1b39", "8bf361e85f0f9dbff5b9d6951fdae8c6", 
"0c7b675ddf75b3a6ad648b004352b8c1", "f3ed29d9b4cd4e1ea7861fbe19314125", 
"4aafbcb8ea0c9be6130d630345116249", "1d926e22515426e147f62e2d27fb25d5", 
"6357497de4b956c00e393b9cbebaf228", "c8c6649cf27d3428a978248cb233b4ea", 
"6013a4618dd16c1f100b084d722a817d", "fd188dccbbfa7e8d7aa3b6abe7fe59c4", 
"c04b4c2c12d6408b4e741b3b91e91354", "4a43d5d77936e5dc6536931101c8d814", 
"55982fe768843d5432c485e19f3ca7ae", "498128a80a796620b238d8ad5cd1d2f9", 
"8c2d1b95d59fa2a627dd63d7a36c7483", "2ea78aa082eeffffc40ad0ac7e84dbb8", 
"b8b381bb5c8bfaf50f1916a102161d01", "fe6a40c9234f9a57e1db10d0d87e3fa0", 
"71727d41e7a3452a196977be7f013cb0"), class = "factor"), sample = c("m3ofair", 
"m3NC", "m3ofair", "m3NC", "m3NC"), value = c(0.00110121133246571, 
0, 0.00200220242266493, 0.00943847890021202, 0), Kingdom = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("d__Archaea", "d__Bacteria"), class = "factor"), 
    Phylum = structure(c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("p__Acidobacteriota", 
    "p__Actinobacteriota", "p__Armatimonadota", "p__Bacteroidota", 
    "p__Chloroflexi", "p__Cyanobacteria", "p__Deinococcota", 
    "p__Desulfobacterota", "p__Firmicutes", "p__Fusobacteriota", 
    "p__Gemmatimonadota", "p__Myxococcota", "p__Patescibacteria", 
    "p__Planctomycetota", "p__Proteobacteria", "p__SAR324_clade(Marine_group_B)", 
    "p__Synergistota", "p__Thermoplasmatota", "p__Verrucomicrobiota", 
    "p__WPS-2"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("c__Acidimicrobiia", "c__Acidobacteriae", 
    "c__Actinobacteria", "c__Alphaproteobacteria", "c__Bacilli", 
    "c__Bacteroidia", "c__Chloroflexia", "c__Clostridia", "c__Coriobacteriia", 
    "c__CPR2", "c__Cyanobacteriia", "c__Deinococci", "c__Desulfitobacteriia", 
    "c__Desulfotomaculia", "c__Fimbriimonadia", "c__Fusobacteriia", 
    "c__Gammaproteobacteria", "c__Gemmatimonadetes", "c__KD4-96", 
    "c__Ktedonobacteria", "c__Myxococcia", "c__Phycisphaerae", 
    "c__Planctomycetes", "c__Polyangia", "c__Rhodothermia", "c__SAR324_clade(Marine_group_B)", 
    "c__Sericytochromatia", "c__Synergistia", "c__Syntrophia", 
    "c__Thermoanaerobacteria", "c__Thermoanaerobaculia", "c__Thermoleophilia", 
    "c__Thermoplasmata", "c__TK10", "c__Verrucomicrobiae", "c__Vicinamibacteria", 
    "c__WPS-2"), class = "factor"), Order = structure(c(72L, 
    7L, 7L, 72L, 72L), .Label = c("o__Acetobacterales", "o__Acidobacteriales", 
    "o__Actinomarinales", "o__Actinomycetales", "o__Alteromonadales", 
    "o__Arctic97B-4_marine_group", "o__Azospirillales", "o__Bacillales", 
    "o__Bacteroidales", "o__Balneolales", "o__Bifidobacteriales", 
    "o__Burkholderiales", "o__C0119", "o__Caulobacterales", "o__Chitinophagales", 
    "o__Chthoniobacterales", "o__Clostridia", "o__Clostridiales", 
    "o__Corynebacteriales", "o__CPR2", "o__Cyanobacteriales", 
    "o__Cytophagales", "o__Deinococcales", "o__Desulfitobacteriales", 
    "o__Desulfotomaculales", "o__Elsterales", "o__Enterobacterales", 
    "o__Eubacteriales", "o__Fimbriimonadales", "o__Flavobacteriales", 
    "o__Frankiales", "o__Fusobacteriales", "o__Gaiellales", "o__Gemmatales", 
    "o__Gemmatimonadales", "o__Haliangiales", "o__Halothiobacillales", 
    "o__IMCC26256", "o__Isosphaerales", "o__KD4-96", "o__Kiloniellales", 
    "o__Kineosporiales", "o__Ktedonobacterales", "o__Lachnospirales", 
    "o__Lactobacillales", "o__Legionellales", "o__Marine_Group_II", 
    "o__Methylococcales", "o__Micrococcales", "o__Micromonosporales", 
    "o__Micropepsales", "o__Microtrichales", "o__Myxococcales", 
    "o__Nitriliruptorales", "o__Nitrococcales", "o__Nitrosococcales", 
    "o__Oceanospirillales", "o__OPB41", "o__Oscillospirales", 
    "o__Paenibacillales", "o__Parvibaculales", "o__PeM15", "o__Peptostreptococcales-Tissierellales", 
    "o__Phycisphaerales", "o__Pirellulales", "o__Polyangiales", 
    "o__Propionibacteriales", "o__Proteinivoracales", "o__Pseudomonadales", 
    "o__Pseudonocardiales", "o__Puniceispirillales", "o__Rhizobiales", 
    "o__Rhodobacterales", "o__Rhodospirillales", "o__Rhodothermales", 
    "o__Rickettsiales", "o__Salinisphaerales", "o__SAR324_clade(Marine_group_B)", 
    "o__SAR86_clade", "o__Sericytochromatia", "o__Solibacterales", 
    "o__Solirubrobacterales", "o__Sphingobacteriales", "o__Sphingomonadales", 
    "o__Staphylococcales", "o__Streptomycetales", "o__Streptosporangiales", 
    "o__Synechococcales", "o__Synergistales", "o__Syntrophales", 
    "o__Thalassobaculales", "o__Thermales", "o__Thermoanaerobacterales", 
    "o__Thermoanaerobaculales", "o__Thermomicrobiales", "o__Tistrellales", 
    "o__TK10", "o__Vicinamibacterales", "o__WPS-2", "o__Xanthomonadales"
    ), class = "factor"), Family = structure(c(17L, 13L, 13L, 
    17L, 17L), .Label = c("f__67-14", "f__Acetobacteraceae", 
    "f__Acidobacteriaceae_(Subgroup_1)", "f__Actinomarinaceae", 
    "f__Actinomycetaceae", "f__Aerococcaceae", "f__Alcaligenaceae", 
    "f__Alcanivoracaceae1", "f__Algiphilaceae", "f__Alkalibacteraceae", 
    "f__Anaeromyxobacteraceae", "f__Arctic97B-4_marine_group", 
    "f__Azospirillaceae", "f__Bacillaceae", "f__Bacteroidetes_vadinHA17", 
    "f__Balneolaceae", "f__Beijerinckiaceae", "f__Beutenbergiaceae", 
    "f__Bifidobacteriaceae", "f__Bogoriellaceae", "f__Brevibacteriaceae", 
    "f__C0119", "f__Carnobacteriaceae", "f__Caulobacteraceae", 
    "f__Cellulomonadaceae", "f__Chitinophagaceae", "f__Chroococcidiopsaceae", 
    "f__Chthoniobacteraceae", "f__Clostridiaceae", "f__Comamonadaceae", 
    "f__Corynebacteriaceae", "f__CPR2", "f__Crocinitomicaceae", 
    "f__Cyanobiaceae", "f__Cyclobacteriaceae", "f__Deinococcaceae", 
    "f__Demequinaceae", "f__Dermabacteraceae", "f__Dermacoccaceae", 
    "f__Desulfitobacteriaceae", "f__Desulfotomaculales", "f__Devosiaceae", 
    "f__Dietziaceae", "f__Dysgonomonadaceae", "f__Endozoicomonadaceae", 
    "f__Enterobacteriaceae", "f__Eubacteriaceae", "f__Family_III", 
    "f__Fimbriimonadaceae", "f__Flavobacteriaceae", "f__Fodinicurvataceae", 
    "f__Frankiaceae", "f__Fusobacteriaceae", "f__Geminicoccaceae", 
    "f__Gemmataceae", "f__Gemmatimonadaceae", "f__Geodermatophilaceae", 
    "f__Haliangiaceae", "f__Halomonadaceae", "f__Halorhodospiraceae", 
    "f__Hungateiclostridiaceae", "f__Hymenobacteraceae", "f__Hyphomicrobiaceae", 
    "f__Hyphomonadaceae", "f__Idiomarinaceae", "f__IMCC26256", 
    "f__Intrasporangiaceae", "f__Isosphaeraceae", "f__JG30-KF-CM45", 
    "f__Jonesiaceae", "f__Kangiellaceae", "f__KD4-96", "f__Kineosporiaceae", 
    "f__Ktedonobacteraceae", "f__Labraceae", "f__Lachnospiraceae", 
    "f__Lactobacillaceae", "f__Legionellaceae", "f__Marine_Group_II", 
    "f__Marinilabiliaceae", "f__Marinobacteraceae", "f__Marinococcaceae", 
    "f__Methylomonadaceae", "f__Methylophagaceae", "f__Methylophilaceae", 
    "f__Methylopilaceae", "f__Microbacteriaceae", "f__Micrococcaceae", 
    "f__Micromonosporaceae", "f__Micropepsaceae", "f__Microscillaceae", 
    "f__Moraxellaceae", "f__Morganellaceae", "f__Mycobacteriaceae", 
    "f__Myxococcaceae", "f__Nakamurellaceae", "f__Nitriliruptoraceae", 
    "f__Nitrosomonadaceae", "f__Nocardiaceae", "f__Nocardioidaceae", 
    "f__Nocardiopsaceae", "f__Nostocaceae", "f__Oceanibaculaceae", 
    "f__OPB41", "f__Oscillospiraceae", "f__Oxalobacteraceae", 
    "f__Paenibacillaceae", "f__Parvibaculaceae", "f__PeM15", 
    "f__Peptostreptococcales-Tissierellales", "f__Phaselicystidaceae", 
    "f__Phycisphaeraceae", "f__Pirellulaceae", "f__Planococcaceae", 
    "f__Prevotellaceae", "f__Prolixibacteraceae", "f__Promicromonosporaceae", 
    "f__Proteinivoracales", "f__Pseudomonadaceae", "f__Pseudonocardiaceae", 
    "f__Rhizobiaceae", "f__Rhizobiales_Incertae_Sedis", "f__Rhodobacteraceae", 
    "f__Rhodobiaceae", "f__Rhodothermaceae", "f__Rickettsiaceae", 
    "f__Ruminococcaceae", "f__S25-593", "f__Salisediminibacteriaceae", 
    "f__SAR116_clade", "f__SAR324_clade(Marine_group_B)", "f__SAR86_clade", 
    "f__SC-I-84", "f__Sedimentibacteraceae", "f__Sericytochromatia", 
    "f__Solibacteraceae", "f__Solirubrobacteraceae", "f__Sphingobacteriaceae", 
    "f__Sphingomonadaceae", "f__Spirosomaceae", "f__Staphylococcaceae", 
    "f__Stappiaceae", "f__Streptococcaceae", "f__Streptomycetaceae", 
    "f__Streptosporangiaceae", "f__Synergistaceae", "f__Syntrophaceae", 
    "f__Syntrophobotulaceae", "f__Thalassospiraceae", "f__Thermaceae", 
    "f__Thermoanaerobaculaceae", "f__Thermotaleaceae", "f__Thioalkalibacteraceae", 
    "f__Tistrellaceae", "f__TK10", "f__TRA3-20", "f__uncultured", 
    "f__Vicinamibacteraceae", "f__Weeksellaceae", "f__WPS-2", 
    "f__Xanthobacteraceae", "f__Xanthomonadaceae"), class = "factor"), 
    Genus = structure(c(125L, 28L, 28L, 125L, NA), .Label = c("g__67-14", 
    "g__Acetobacterium", "g__Acidiphilium", "g__Acinetobacter", 
    "g__Actinomyces", "g__Actinotalea", "g__Advenella", "g__Aerococcus", 
    "g__Alcanivorax", "g__Algiphilus", "g__Algoriphagus", "g__Aliidiomarina", 
    "g__Aliihoeflea", "g__Aliterella", "g__Alkalibacter", "g__Allorhizobium-Neorhizobium-Pararhizobium-Rhizobium", 
    "g__Altererythrobacter", "g__Amorphus", "g__Amycolatopsis", 
    "g__Anaerobacillus", "g__Anaerobranca", "g__Anaeromyxobacter", 
    "g__Aquibacillus", "g__Arctic97B-4_marine_group", "g__Arenimonas", 
    "g__Arthrobacter", "g__Aureimonas", "g__Azospirillum", "g__Bacillus", 
    "g__Bacteroidetes_vadinHA17", "g__Bauldia", "g__Bifidobacterium", 
    "g__Blastococcus", "g__Blastopirellula", "g__Bosea", "g__Brachybacterium", 
    "g__Bradyrhizobium", "g__Brevibacterium", "g__Brevundimonas", 
    "g__C0119", "g__Candidatus_Actinomarina", "g__Candidatus_Alysiosphaera", 
    "g__Candidatus_Solibacter", "g__Candidatus_Udaeobacter", 
    "g__Cecembia", "g__Chromohalobacter", "g__Chryseobacterium", 
    "g__Chthoniobacter", "g__Citricoccus", "g__Cloacibacterium", 
    "g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_9", "g__Conexibacter", "g__Corynebacterium", 
    "g__CPR2", "g__Craurococcus-Caldovatus", "g__Curtobacterium", 
    "g__Dehalobacter", "g__Deinococcus", "g__Demequina", "g__Dermacoccus", 
    "g__Desulfohalotomaculum", "g__Desulfosporosinus", "g__Devosia", 
    "g__Dietzia", "g__DSSD61", "g__Dyadobacter", "g__Egicoccus", 
    "g__Ellin6067", "g__Endozoicomonas", "g__Enhydrobacter", 
    "g__Ercella", "g__Escherichia-Shigella", "g__Faecalibacterium", 
    "g__Fermentimonas", "g__Fimbriiglobus", "g__Fimbriimonadaceae", 
    "g__Finegoldia", "g__Flaviflexus", "g__Flavobacterium", "g__Fluviicola", 
    "g__Fusicatenibacter", "g__Fusobacterium", "g__Gardnerella", 
    "g__Gemmatimonas", "g__Geobacillus", "g__Georgenia", "g__Glutamicibacter", 
    "g__Gracilibacillus", "g__Gracilimonas", "g__Guyparkeria", 
    "g__Haematobacter", "g__Haliangium", "g__Halolactibacillus", 
    "g__Halomonas", "g__Henriciella", "g__HIMB11", "g__HSB_OF53-F07", 
    "g__Hymenobacter", "g__Hyphomicrobium", "g__IMCC26256", "g__Janibacter", 
    "g__Jatrophihabitans", "g__JCM_18997", "g__Jeotgalibacillus", 
    "g__JG30-KF-CM45", "g__JG30a-KF-32", "g__JGI-0000079-D21", 
    "g__Jiella", "g__Jonesia", "g__KD4-96", "g__Kineococcus", 
    "g__Labrys", "g__Lactobacillus", "g__Lawsonella", "g__Leeuwenhoekiella", 
    "g__Legionella", "g__Marine_Group_II", "g__Marinilabiliaceae", 
    "g__Marinobacter", "g__Marinococcus", "g__Martelella", "g__Massilia", 
    "g__Meiothermus", "g__Methylobacillus", "g__Methylobacterium-Methylorubrum", 
    "g__Methylophaga", "g__Methylotenera", "g__Micrococcus", 
    "g__Microvirga", "g__Modestobacter", "g__Mucilaginibacter", 
    "g__Muricauda", "g__Mycobacterium", "g__Nakamurella", "g__Nesterenkonia", 
    "g__Nitratireductor", "g__Nitriliruptor", "g__Nitriliruptoraceae", 
    "g__Nocardia", "g__Nocardioides", "g__Nocardiopsis", "g__Novosphingobium", 
    "g__NS5_marine_group", "g__Oceanibaculum", "g__Oceanobacillus", 
    "g__OPB41", "g__Oricola", "g__Ornithinimicrobium", "g__Oryzihumus", 
    "g__P3OB-42", "g__Paenibacillus", "g__Paludisphaera", "g__Paracoccus", 
    "g__Paraliobacillus", "g__Parvibaculum", "g__Patulibacter", 
    "g__Pediococcus", "g__Pedomicrobium", "g__Pelagibacterium", 
    "g__Pelotomaculum", "g__PeM15", "g__Phaselicystis", "g__Phenylobacterium", 
    "g__Pir4_lineage", "g__Polaromonas", "g__Prevotella", "g__Prochlorococcus_MIT9313", 
    "g__Promicromonospora", "g__Proteiniclasticum", "g__Pseudolabrys", 
    "g__Pseudomonas", "g__Pseudonocardia", "g__Psychrobacter", 
    "g__Psychroglaciecola", "g__Pusillimonas", "g__Quadrisphaera", 
    "g__Rhodococcus", "g__Rhodopirellula", "g__Roseisolibacter", 
    "g__Roseovarius", "g__Rubrivirga", "g__Rummeliibacillus", 
    "g__S25-593", "g__Saccharomonospora", "g__Saccharopolyspora", 
    "g__Salegentibacter", "g__Salimesophilobacter", "g__Salinicola", 
    "g__Salipaludibacillus", "g__SAR116_clade", "g__SAR324_clade(Marine_group_B)", 
    "g__SAR86_clade", "g__SC-I-84", "g__Scytonema_UTEX_2349", 
    "g__Sedimentibacter", "g__Sediminibacterium", "g__Sericytochromatia", 
    "g__SM1A02", "g__Solirubrobacter", "g__Sphingobium", "g__Sphingomonas", 
    "g__Sporobacter", "g__Staphylococcus", "g__Stappia", "g__Streptococcus", 
    "g__Streptomyces", "g__Subgroup_10", "g__Synechococcus_CC9902", 
    "g__Syntrophus", "g__Terrabacter", "g__Thalassospira", "g__Thermoanaerobacterium", 
    "g__Thermopolyspora", "g__Thermus", "g__Tistrella", "g__TK10", 
    "g__TRA3-20", "g__uncultured", "g__Vicinamibacteraceae", 
    "g__Virgibacillus", "g__WCHB1-32", "g__WPS-2", "g__Xanthobacter"
    ), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(NA, 55L, 55L, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("s__Acetobacteraceae_bacterium", "s__Acinetobacter_venetianus", 
    "s__Actinomycetales_bacterium", "s__Alcanivorax_pacificus", 
    "s__Amorphus_suaedae", "s__Aquibacillus_sp.", "s__Bacillus_alcalophilus", 
    "s__bacterium_Ellin6515", "s__bacterium_enrichment", "s__bacterium_QTYC46b", 
    "s__Bifidobacterium_bifidum", "s__Blastopirellula_cremea", 
    "s__Brevibacterium_samyangense", "s__Cellulomonas_sp.", "s__Corynebacterium_glaucum", 
    "s__Deinococcus_geothermalis", "s__Desulfohalotomaculum_halophilum", 
    "s__Desulfosporosinus_youngiae", "s__Endozoicomonas_acroporae", 
    "s__Ercella_succinigenes", "s__Flavobacterium_qiangtangense", 
    "s__Fluviicola_sp.", "s__Gardnerella_vaginalis", "s__iron-reducing_bacterium", 
    "s__Jonesia_denitrificans", "s__Lactobacillus_iners", "s__Leeuwenhoekiella_sp.", 
    "s__marine_sediment", "s__Mesorhizobium_sp.", "s__metagenome", 
    "s__Nitriliruptor_alkaliphilus", "s__Oryzihumus_terrae", 
    "s__Pedomicrobium_ferrugineum", "s__Phyllobacteriaceae_bacterium", 
    "s__planctomycete_str.", "s__Prevotella_histicola", "s__Prevotella_pallens", 
    "s__Psychrobacter_pulmonis", "s__Rhodobacteraceae_bacterium", 
    "s__Rhodococcus_sp.", "s__rock_porewater", "s__Saccharopolyspora_rectivirgula", 
    "s__Sedimentibacter_acidaminivorans", "s__Sphingomonas_metalli", 
    "s__Streptomyces_specialis", "s__Streptosporangiaceae_str.", 
    "s__Tistrella_bauzanensis", "s__Triticum_aestivum", "s__uncultured_Acidobacteriaceae", 
    "s__uncultured_actinobacterium", "s__uncultured_Actinomycetales", 
    "s__uncultured_Alcaligenes", "s__uncultured_Anaerobacillus", 
    "s__uncultured_Anaerolineaceae", "s__uncultured_Azospirillum", 
    "s__uncultured_bacterium", "s__uncultured_Bacteroidetes", 
    "s__uncultured_Chloroflexi", "s__uncultured_Conexibacter", 
    "s__uncultured_cyanobacterium", "s__uncultured_Ferrimicrobium", 
    "s__uncultured_Fimbriimonas", "s__uncultured_Ktedobacteria", 
    "s__uncultured_Methylocystaceae", "s__uncultured_Nitriliruptorales", 
    "s__uncultured_planctomycete", "s__uncultured_Porphyromonadaceae", 
    "s__uncultured_prokaryote", "s__uncultured_Rhodospirillaceae", 
    "s__uncultured_soil"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(86L, 
209L, 210L, 333L, 431L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you working with a `phyloseq` object?

Comment: Why, yes I am! Hopefully that's a good thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a [phyloseq](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/phyloseq.html) object called `physeq` you can do the following:

1. Agglomerate the OTU table to Family level:

```
   p <- tax_glom(physeq, "Family")
```

2. Then you can select families that are present in both samples:

```
    families <- tax_table(p)[otu_table(p)[,"m3ofair"] > 0 & otu_table(p)[,"m3NC"] > 0, "Family"]
```

3. Now you can select the ASVs with the families you want:

```
    pout <- prune_taxa(tax_table(physeq)[, "Family"] %in% families, physeq)
```